# Sharepoint - Soap web service - Given list name, how to get list GUID?

Tags: sharepoint, soap

Given a sharepoint list *name*, is there an easy way using soap web service to get the List?

I am currently having to call `getListCollection` to do it. But this returns *everything* which is performance constraining now due to size of collection.

And `getList` doesn't work. It just returns the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Check for ID field in the XML response